# ASP RadioButtonList .Selected Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button list inside of an AJAX panel. Here is the radio button list:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="true">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Option3" Value="Option3" Selected="True" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Option1" Value="Option1" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Option2" Value="Option2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I have a function that loads the value based on saved settings. It looks similar to this:

```
string selectedOption = savedRecord.RadioButtonListValue.ToString();
RadioButtonList.Items.FindByValue(selectedOption).Selected = true;
```

It only seems to correctly load the value if I haven't changed the selected option.

- If I load the page, the load the settings it will correctly set to the saved option.
- If I load the page, change the option, then load the settings it will not change the option.

I have tried with AutoPostBack set to true and false and it doesn't seem to change the result. Any ideas?

I have been able to hard code a value and it seems to always load correctly:

```
//Working
RadioButtonList.Items.FindByValue("Option1").Selected = true;

//Not-working
string selectedOption = savedRecord.RadioButtonListValue.ToString(); //"Option1"
RadioButtonList.Items.FindByValue(selectedOption).Selected = true;
```

[Here are the combinations that I have come up with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnTo3.png)

Comment: How and where are you saving the data?

Comment: It's being saved as an XML string in a SQL database. I have put breakpoints and verified when the data is being loaded it's the correct value. The data is loaded once a user selects a "load saved settings" option.

Comment: Have you confirmed that **selectedOption** contains the correct values to search for?

Comment: Yes. I stepped over the line setting the value and inspected RadioButtonList.SelectedValue and it shows the correct option. It doesn't display the change on the screen though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the ASPX code will look something like this:

```html
The ASPX code will look something like this:

 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblist1" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item4" Value="4" />

    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="select value" />
```

And the code behind:

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedValue = rblist1.SelectedValue;
            Response.Write(selectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. .SelectedValue seems to work. I can't believe I had kept banging my head trying to use .Selected. Thanks!